# Getting Lego error passing email address using --email

Tags: lets-encrypt, bitnami

To renew a LetsEncrypt certificate I was following this [Bitnami doc](https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/how-to/generate-install-lets-encrypt-ssl/#step-5-renew-the-lets-encrypt-certificate) and:

```
sudo /opt/bitnami/letsencrypt/lego --tls --email="somebody@example.com" --domains="example.com" --domains="www.example.com" --path="/opt/bitnami/letsencrypt" renew --days 90
```

kept returning the error:

You have to pass an account (email address) to the program using --email or -m

I tried retyping the hyphens and quotations in case they were being changed to en dashes and inverted commas in copy/paste, but no luck. Appreciate pointers to what I may be doing wrong or could do differently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bitnami Engineer here. It seems you have an old version of the lego binary in your instance, you have 2 options:

- Use that previous version: In this case you will need to run this command instead

```
sudo /opt/bitnami/letsencrypt/lego --email="somebody@example.com" --domains="example.com" --domains="www.example.com" --path="/opt/bitnami/letsencrypt" renew --days 90
```

> Note: I removed the --tls parameter

- Update the lego binary

```
cd /tmp
curl -Ls https://api.github.com/repos/xenolf/lego/releases/latest | grep browser_download_url | grep linux_amd64 | cut -d '"' -f 4 | wget -i -
tar xf lego_v2.6.0_linux_amd64.tar.gz
sudo mkdir -p /opt/bitnami/letsencrypt
sudo mv lego /opt/bitnami/letsencrypt/lego
```

> Note: 2.6.0 was the latest version of the lego binary when writing this message

and then run your command again

```
sudo /opt/bitnami/letsencrypt/lego --tls --email="somebody@example.com" --domains="example.com" --domains="www.example.com" --path="/opt/bitnami/letsencrypt" renew --days 90
```

I hope this helps

Comment: Thank you, dropped --tls  and all good. I will update the binary in due course.