# Lego keeps giving me error about my email when setting up SSL

Tags: ssl, lets-encrypt, bitnami, lego-mindstorms

I've been using [this](https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/how-to/generate-install-lets-encrypt-ssl/) tutorial from Bitnami's site to set up an SSL certificate on my AWS Lightsail server running Apache via Lets Encrypt and Lego. But when I put in the following code:

```
 sudo /opt/bitnami/letsencrypt/lego --tls --email="my-email@yahoo.com" --domains="bigsheepcollective.com" --domains="www.bigsheepcollective.com" --path="/opt/bitnami/letsencrypt" run
```

I get "You have to pass an account (email address) to the program using --email or -m". The email I'm putting in is valid, so I'm not sure what the deal is.

Any suggestions are helpful!

Comment: You probably have the same issue with this one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56524333/11630054), answered by Jota Martos. Please upvote the answer if his solutions helped you with this issue. Thanks!

Comment: This did the trick, thank you!